# ¿Como logro un SEO amigable con angular2 y puppeeter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, puppeteer

Tengo un proyecto el cual use para llevar a cabo Angular7, se trata de renderizado de vistas para peticiones HTTP al API de Wordpress de mi proyecto. Ya termine el proyecto en Angular, pero necesito optimizar el SEO del proyecto, he buscado por google y diferentes páginas, y se puede lograr con un prerenderizado del proyecto de angular, en este caso escogí Puppeeter para llevar a cabo dicho proceso, mi duda es la siguiente:
Como puedo lograr un SEO amigable con angular y Puppeeter?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y trata mejorar el contenido de tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola Aprendiz ya modifique la pregunta, la puedes responder?